# How to import a ed25519 private key into Yubi HSM 2

Tags: openssl, hsm, yubico, ed25519

I am trying to import a openssl generated ed25519 key into Yubi HSM 2
I am following the steps described here: https://developers.yubico.com/yubihsm-shell/yubihsm-wrap.html

```
echo -en '\x00\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff' >wrap.key
```

```
yubihsm-shell -p password -a put-wrap-key -i 20 -c all --delegated all --informat bin --in wrap.key
```

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm Ed25519 -out ed25519key.pem
```

```
yubihsm-wrap -a ed25519 -c sign-eddsa -d 1,2,5 --id 30 --label ED25519_Key --in ed25519key.pem --wrapkey wrap.key --out private.yhw
```

```
yubihsm-shell -p password -a put-wrapped --wrap-id 20 --in private.yhw
```

Finally my error is `Malformed command / invalid data`

There seem to be no indication that wrapping ed25519 key are not supported by Yubi HSM 2.

Is there something wrong in my process or it is simply not supported?

Comment: For key wrap it says `Import and export using NIST-approved AES-CCM Wrap with 128, 196, and 256 bit keys`, see their product brochure [here](https://developers.yubico.com/YubiHSM2/Product_Overview/). So looking at that it doesn't support importing `ed25519`

Comment: It is still unclear to me why it would mean that there is no support for ed25519, `AES-CCM Wrap with 128, 196, and 256 bit keys` refers to the method used to wrap object not the actual object being imported. For instance, I have been able to import p256 and secp256k1 private key with no problem using an AES key of 256 bits

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure if `ed25519` is NIST certified though, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51012/could-a-c25519-ed25519-cryptographic-module-be-fips-certified

Comment: Ok yes that might be it, I am trying to validate this with Yubi Support and if it turns out to be confirmed, please write your comment as an answer so I can give you the bounty reward.

Answer (score 3):

Although ed25519 meets the general requirements, there has been no follow up on FIPS 186-4 as of yet. NIST has not issued a certification.

[https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/186/4/final/documents/comments-received-fips186-4-december-2015.pdf]

If / when they do it will likely be supported.